# XmlSerializer omit encoding attribute

Tags: .net, xml, encoding

Is it possible to instruct .NET's XmlSerializer to serialize XML documents to the following format:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE root SYSTEM "root.dtd">
<root>
...
</root>
```

i.e. XML declaration *without* the encoding attribute, doctype and then the rest of the document?

Currently I have:

```
var bomlessUtf8Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false);
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
var namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
namespaces.Add(string.Empty, string.Empty);

using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(memoryStream, new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = false, Encoding = null }))
{
    xmlWriter.WriteDocType(typeof(T).Name, null, ContentSerializer.MlpSvcInit320Dtd, null);
    serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, input, namespaces);

    return bomlessUtf8Encoding.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
}
```

but .NET is barking when creating the XmlWriterSettings object due to Encoding being null. Is there a canonical way, or is it easiest to simply serialize to a string and then call `.Replace()` on it?

Unfortunately, a third party vendor requires the serialized string to be exactly in this format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XmlTextWriter` gets you the possibility of remove `encoding` attribute. If you pass `null` as encoding, xml will be encoded using UTF-8, but `encoding` attribute will be removed.

So something like this:

```
using(var xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(memoryStream, null))
```

should be suitable. You can also set `Indent` etc, refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks! It looks like it works (although I have to call `WriteStartDocument()` manually). Is there a way to do this with `XmlWriter` too? Documentation of `XmlTextWriter` contains the note »Starting with the .NET Framework 2.0, we recommend that you use the System.Xml.XmlWriter class instead.«

Comment: Hey, I do not really know. Maybe this blog post will help: http://www.cookcomputing.com/blog/archives/000577.html , it involves overriding some classes, looks like overkill for me.

Comment: I verify the generated string in unit tests. Sometimes I still get the encoding attribute. There seems to be some sort of race condition (it only is inserted, if I execute other tests together). I create a new `XmlTextWriter` instance each time I serialize the XML. What could be happening?

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea - I've never seen that.

Comment: Seems to be a false alarm. Somehow nunit must have got hold of the previously built dll. Cannot reproduce the error right now.